# Javascript/JQuery getting data to process

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

For my site, I'm trying to figure out a way to get data that will be used to output a result.

e.g. user chooses: 16 GB RAM, 2 GB graphic card, full HD screen, i5 intel.
Site checks all of the laptops with these specs and outputs the laptops.

Data is stored like this:

```
laptop1,RAM: 16GB,graphic card: 2GB,screen quality: Full HD,processor: i5,laptop img: https;//bla.com
laptop1,RAM: 16GB,graphic card: 2GB,screen quality: Full HD,processor: i5,laptop img: https;//bla.com
```

(Data format can be changed if another format is better)

Best I could think of is putting it in a JSON file and using JQuery to load it with AJAX

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

The JSON would be

```
{
  "laptop" : "laptop1", laptop2", "laptop3",
  "ram" : "5GB", "16GB", "32GB",
  "graphic card" : "1GB","2GB","3GB"
}
```

OR JSON would be

```
{
"laptop" : "laptop1",
"ram" " "16GB",
"Graphic card" : "2GB"
}
```

you get the idea...

BUT, I've got data with over 900 laptops which all have a lot of specs. Which would mean I would have to spend some decades creating the JSON and updating them every week.

My Question would be how do I store that info so that I can call it into the website in order to process it?

Comment: Use a relational database for this. Then retrieving the data becomes a very simple query. Using JSON for it is not a maintainable, extensible or scalable solution. Unless this is just for coursework, of course.

Comment: That's exactly what databases are for. You can query them, something like `find "laptop" where ram=16 AND cpu=i5`, tadaaaaa. Look up MongoDB (my personal favorite, stores and works directly with JSON), MySQL, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a tutorial on that you recommend?